# How to SSH, verify if update is available. If yes, download the update

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scp

I have the following script to check for update, if available, download all the update, but it is not efficient because it needs to login SSH twice.  Any comment is welcome to make it better

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check configuration update every hour
# version 1.0
if ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa abc@azx.example.com test -e /home/abc/update \> /dev/null 2\>\&1 ; then
    rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa" abc@azx.example.com:/home/abc/ghz_upd/ /tmp/ghz
    cd /tmp/ghz
    sh ./ghz_upd.sh
    rm -r /tmp/ghz
else
    echo Not found
fi
```

Comment: Please clarify by editing your question. Is this about machine efficiency, or about human efficiency? Are you being prompted for passwd 2x? Or is that working, and your concerned about 2 sshs? Isn't there an rsync OR scp option that only copies new and updated files? Good luck.

Comment: I think you get your requested feature for free with `rsync -a` -- that implies `-r` which uses incremental scans.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use *ControlMaster* feature, which makes it possible for multiple ssh processess to share a single connection.

To configure it for a given host, add the following into your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
host *.example.com
Controlmaster yes                               
Controlpath ~/.ssh/socket/%r@%h:%p
```